# bracha only on etrog: can I do anything with just an etrog

Tags: halacha, mistakes, travel, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Someone is on a plane/transit for an entire daylight period of Sukkot and accidentally only brought along their etrog, leaving left the rest at home ;~

Is there anything to do with just the etrog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ד' מינים הללו מעכבין זה את זה שאם חסר לו אחד מהם לא יברך על השאר, אבל נוטלן לזכר בעלמא (בין ביום א' בין בשאר ימים)‏
>   These four species restrict each other such that if he was missing one of them he does not bless on the rest, but he takes them as merely a remembrance. ([Shulchan Aruch OC 651:12](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3035))

So you should just pick up the Etrog during the day as a remembrance to the Mitzva.

Aruch haShulchan there ([:28](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A8.D7.A0.D7.90_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9B.D7.97)) quotes two opinions regarding if you should shake the Etrog or just pick it up.

Comment: is the taking of Aravos on hoshana raba dependent on having made a bracha on all 4 species earlier in davening? If my etrog lost its pitom so according to this quote, the other 3 are retricted, what do I do with aravos? Or because I will take extra aravos to hit with, mine are not restricted?

Comment: @Danno All of that could be in separate posts, but to answer quickly: the aravot on hoshana rabba are independent, and a pitom-less etrog is kosher on the latter days of sukkot.

Comment: thanks -- half way through I figured it could be a separate question but I was riffing on the specific halacha you posted so I just went with it.